# Building active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to build a query such that if a driver sends an offer to a ride, that ride no longer shows up in the collection rendered in the index view.
I've tried so many variations and I'm still getting all the rides. Even the ones Ive sent an offer to.

```
lang - ruby
class Driver < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :offers
  has_many :rides
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rides
  has_one :driver
end

class Ride < ApplicationRecord
  validates :to, presence: true
  validates :from, presence: true
  validates :directions_from, presence: true
  has_many :offers
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :driver, optional: true
end

lang - ruby
class Driver < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :offers
  has_many :rides
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rides
  has_one :driver
end

class Ride < ApplicationRecord
  validates :to, presence: true
  validates :from, presence: true
  validates :directions_from, presence: true
  has_many :offers
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :driver, optional: true
end

class Offer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ride
  belongs_to :driver
end

def index
  @location = current_user.currently_at
  @rides = Ride.includes(:driver).where(from: @location).select do |ride|
    ride.offers.map do |offer|
      offer.driver.user != current_user
    end
  end
  @offer = Offer.new
end
```

Comment: Tried it. 
`NoMethodError: undefined method `joins' for #<User id:`

Comment: Sorry `Rides.where.not(id: current_user.driver.offers.select(:ride_id))`